# Use Hastag # in Google Analytics New analytics.js tracking code

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the new Google Analytics code (below) and need it to be able to track # URLs.  I can do it in the old tracking code but am unshure of how to do it in this new code.  Ideally I would love to be able to stick the tracking code into the header of all pages without modification and have it grab the # from the URL.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have check out this page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages but am still unsure of exactly how to do what I want.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-2433430-6', 'mydomain.org');
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: What's your old tracking code look like?

Comment: Take a look at the technical part of GA documentation, which referrers to anchors: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'allowAnchor': false});
```

from here : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#allowAnchor